# Android: Hiding/removing a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

What is a good way to go about hiding/removing a `ViewPager`.  My goal is to hide/remove the `ViewPager` and display a separat `Fragment`?  In my XML, the `ViewPager` and `Fragment` are at the same level, and I want to swap between the two.  Are there any special considerations I need to take to swap them?

I've thought about just changing the visibility on the ViewPager, but I am not sure if this is a bad idea.

I am having a lot of difficulty searching this topic because almost every post is about hiding a fragment **within** a `ViewPager`, and not hiding the `ViewPager` itself.  Any links or tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap between them with an animation you could do a crossfade and when you are finished set the ViewPager's visibility to gone. You would have the other fragment start as gone and then make it visible when you want to switch. But if all you want to do is just swap them set the ViewPager's visibility as View.GONE and the Fragment's visibility as View.VISIBLE.